# Ionic: unable to appendUserAgent

Tags: ionic-framework, user-agent, capacitor

I have an android/ios application with ionic+capacitor. Capacitor version is v5. I want append a custom string to the useragent, but nothing worked.

Here is my config file:

```
        /// <reference types="@capacitor/push-notifications" />
/// <reference types="@capacitor/splash-screen" />

import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
    appId: 'io.icoders.jobinfo',
    appName: 'Jobinfo',
    webDir: 'dist',
    plugins: {
        SplashScreen: {
            launchShowDuration: 5000,
            launchAutoHide: true,
            backgroundColor: '#ffffffff',
            androidSplashResourceName: 'splash',
            androidScaleType: 'CENTER_CROP',
            showSpinner: true,
            androidSpinnerStyle: 'large',
            iosSpinnerStyle: 'small',
            spinnerColor: '#999999',
            splashFullScreen: true,
            splashImmersive: false,
            layoutName: 'launch_screen',
            useDialog: false
        }
    },
    appendUserAgent: 'JobinfoApp',
    overrideUserAgent: 'JobinfoApp',
    android: {
        appendUserAgent: 'JobinfoApp',
        overrideUserAgent: 'JobinfoApp',
    },
    ios: {
        appendUserAgent: 'JobinfoApp',
        overrideUserAgent: 'JobinfoApp',
    }
};

export default config;
```

I already tried the "appendUserAgent" config in ios and android tag, also in the main body, not working, the useragent is restored the original. What is the problem?

Comment:  Capacitor Doctor 

Latest Dependencies:

@capacitor/cli: 5.6.0
@capacitor/core: 5.6.0
@capacitor/android: 5.6.0
@capacitor/ios: 5.6.0

Installed Dependencies:

@capacitor/cli: 5.3.0
@capacitor/core: 5.5.1
@capacitor/android: 5.3.0
@capacitor/ios: 5.5.1

[success] iOS looking great! 
[success] Android looking great! 

Other API Details

npm: 8.19.4
node: v16.20.2
pod: 1.11.2

Comment: can you add your comment to the question or post your own answer, because like this it is unclear if your problem is resolved now or not.